# Vectorize columns replacement based on a vector - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, vectorization

I want to replace value of n-th column of a matrix, based on a vector values, in a vectorized way.
Input:

```
[0 0 0 0]  
[0 0 0 0]  
[0 0 0 0]  
[0 0 0 0]
```

Vector:

```
[2]  
[4]  
[1]  
[3]
```

Expected output:

```
[0 1 0 0]  
[0 0 0 1]  
[1 0 0 0]  
[0 0 1 0]
```

Matlab code with for-loop:

```
A = zeros(4,4);  
b = [2; 4; 1; 3];  
for row=1:4  
   A(row, b(row)) = 1;  
endfor
```

Matlab code with sub2ind:

```
A = zeros(4,4);  
b = [2; 4; 1; 3];  
c = [[1:length(b)]' b];  
A(sub2ind(size(A), c(:,1), c(:,2))) = 1;
```

Is there more vectorized way in Matlab? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *raw version* of [`sub2ind`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to solve it in a vectorized manner -

```
A( (b(:)-1)*size(A,1) + [1:numel(b)]' ) = 1;
```

**How it works:** Since elements of `b` are the column indices and MATLAB follows column-major indexing, so we need to multiply each such column index with the number of rows in `A` to get us the number of elements before starting that column, which would be `(b(:)-1)*size(A,1)`. Then, add the corresponding row indices i.e. `[1:numel(b)]'` to give us the final linear indices, same as the ones produced by `sub2ind`. Finally, index into `A` with those linear indices and set them to all `1`'s as per the question's requirement.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to use subscript indexing instead of linear indexing in Matlab to do the job?

Comment: @silo To do this job, linear indexing seems to be the best bet here.